# Official names for pointer operators

Tags: c++, pointers

What are the official names for the operators `*` and `&` in the context of pointers? They seem to be frequently called *dereference operator* and *address-of operator* respectively, but unfortunately, the section on unary operators in the standard does not name them.

I really don't want to name `&` *address-of* anymore, because `&` returns a pointer, not an address. (see below) The standard is very clear about this:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a **pointer** to its operand.

Symmetry suggests to name `&` *reference operator* which is a little unfortunate because of the collision with references in C++. The fact that `&` returns a pointer suggests *pointer operator*. Are there any official sources that would confirm these (or other) namings?

### pointers vs. addresses

A pointer is a language mechanism, while an address is an implementation detail. Addresses are untyped, while pointers aren't, except for `void*`. Kevlin Henney also distinguishes between pointers and addresses in an [Interview](http://www.se-radio.net/transcript-91-kevlin-henney-c):

> C [...] allows us to abstract the specifics of the machine to the point that we are talking about pointers and not addresses. There is a whole load of pain that you no longer have to go through.

Comment: Great question. I often call them "asterisk" or "star", and "ampersand", operators for lack of anything better.

Comment: Pointers *are* addresses: "§3.9.2/3: A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory or a null pointer." "address of" is suitable; it returns an address in the form of a pointer.

Comment: FWIW, I always call them “dereference operator” and “address-of operator” but your objection to the second name is indeed correct.

Comment: I don't think 'address-of' is a bad name for the operator - it returns a pointer containing the *address of* the operand.

Comment: @Bob Murphy: Those names don't really help since the same glyphs are used for other operators as well (multiplication and bitwise-AND)

Comment: I would not get too concerned about calling & "address-of", ther result can be used to "address" a variable.  Whether that result is a physical or virtual address, or an offset or index into some memory pool or segment or whatever matters little, the term remains unambiguous.  I can think of far more important things to worry about.

Comment: @bmargulies Actually the name of `&` in INTERCAL *is* ampersand. http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/tonsila.html#fn8

Comment: I would submit that all pointers are addresses, but not all addresses are pointers.  So & does return an address.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the C99 draft, at the index:

> `*` (indirection operator), 6.5.2.1, **6.5.3.2**
>
> `&` (address operator), 6.3.2.1, **6.5.3.2**

From the C++0x draft, at the index:

> `*`, *see* indirection operator, *see* multiplication operator
>
> `&`, *see* address-of operator, *see* bitwise AND operator

It's also referenced in 9.6/3 "The address-of operator `&` shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to bit-fields."

(So, sorry, you still need to call `&` "address-of" :p)

Personally I don't care the actual name as long as other can understand what I'm saying. I just call `*` "star" and `&` "and". :)

Comment: That's funny, I found the remark "see address-of operator" in the index, but there is no such entry in the current draft :) There is only one other mentioning of the "address-of operator" on page 219 regarding bit-fields. Am I blind, or can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @Fred: There's an index entry "address-of" (without "operator"). And yes, there's only 1 other mentioning of "address-of operator". In all other places it's just referred as "unary `&` operator".

Answer (score 2):

The official names are address-of (&) (Found in 2.3.3. Pointers and Arrays) and dereference (or indirection operator) (*) (Found in 5.1.Pointers) operators.

according to "The C++ Programming Language", Third Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Can you please post citations or specific pages? It almost sounds too good to be true. Frankly, the Wikipedia article on the dereference operator is an embarrassment. "It operates on a pointer variable"? Wrong. `*(&i)` is well-formed and does not operate on a pointer variable.

Comment: @FredOverflow Sorry, my bad, I found another place where is cleary said that : "Unary & is the address-of operator." (2.3.3.Pointers and Arrays. The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup.) I have edited my answer too.

Answer (score -1):

Not true.

& does not return a pointer.

A pointer is a **variable** of pointer type, that may be used to contain address. Pointer has an address of it's own, usually different from its value, which is the address it holds.

As such, pointer is **lvalue**, and result of &p is not.

Example:

```
int *p, a, b;

p = &b; // valid, p is a pointer
&a = &b; // invalid, address is not a variable. lvalue required
```

Comment: "A pointer is a variable" is a common misconception. If you say that `&` does not return a pointer, you are saying that the standard is wrong, which is extremely unlikely in this basic case.

Comment: In that case `a+b` doesn't return an `int` either because `a+b=*p // invalid, lvalue required`.

Comment: Some pointer variables never have addresses of their own because the compiler may choose to make it exist only in a register and never write it to memory.  That would be the same as using '&foo' in a statement, which generates a 'foo*' temporary that may also only be in a register and may or may not be written to memory.

Comment: Optimization is a different beast. The language always allows you to apply the `&` operator to a pointer variable, and it never allows you to apply it to a pointer. That is, `&p` is never an error, whereas `&(&i)` is always an error.

Comment: @kenny: there is a term for rvalue expression evaluating to address. It is called "address". No need to call it pointer, and the standard doesn't.